# Use of unique on STL vector with a structure

Tags: c++, stl, vector, unique

In a programming task, I'm trying to ensure a particular vector contains only unique items. With primitive types, the operation is as simple as:

```
vector<int> lala;
lala.push_back(1);
lala.push_back(99);
lala.push_back(3);
lala.push_back(99);

sort(lala.begin(), lala.end()); // lala: 1, 3, 99, 99
lala.erase(unique(lala.begin(), lala.end()), lala.end()); // lala: 1, 3, 99
```

However, the problem is I'm not using int. But:

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int maxX;
    int maxY;
    int width;
    int height;
    int id;
} Rect;

bool SameRect(Rect first, Rect second)
{
    return first.x      == second.x &&
           first.y      == second.y &&
           first.width  == second.width &&
           first.height == second.height &&
           first.maxX   == second.maxX &&
           first.maxY   == second.maxY;
}

//...
vector<Rect> lala;
//...
sort(lala.begin(), lala.end());
lala.erase(unique(lala.begin(), lala.end(), SameRect), lala.end());
//...
```

Doesn't really work. What did I done wrong?

EDIT:

With sth's advice, I implemented two sorting predicate for std::sort():

```
bool SortRect(const Rect &first, const Rect &second)
{
    if (first.x < second.x) return true;
    if (first.x > second.x) return false;

    if (first.y < second.y) return true;
    if (first.y > second.y) return false;

    if (first.maxX < second.maxX) return true;
    if (first.maxX > second.maxX) return false;

    if (first.maxY < second.maxY) return true;
    if (first.maxY > second.maxY) return false;

    if (first.width < second.width) return true;
    if (first.width > second.width) return false;

    if (first.height < second.height) return true;
    if (first.height > second.height) return false;

    if (first.id < second.id) return true;
    if (first.id > second.id) return false;

    return false;
}
```

But I found that it has the same effect as:

```
bool SortRect(const Rect &first, const Rect &second)
{
    return first.x < second.x;
}
```

if SGI's documentation is anything to come by. The shorter, simple sorting predicate should work as well. My test has confirmed this (Although I have not try all possible combinations).

Comment: The problem with the shorter comparison is that if you have three rectangles, and I'm ignoring all but the x and y values, (1,1), (1,1), (1,2), then the first SortRect will sort them in that order and unique+erase will remove one of them. The second SortRect *might* sort them in order (1,1), (1,2), (1,1), in which case unique+erase with your specified SameRect will do nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also have to define a comparison function that should be used by `sort()` to sort the Rects. This [comparison function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) should implement a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) so that equal elements end up next to each other in the vector.

If the vector is not sorted, `unique()` will not find the unsorted duplicate elements.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/) in the first place? Its contents are guaranteed to be unique.

*Sidenotes:*
You don't need to `typedef` structs in C++, just `struct Rect {};` is sufficient.
Your comparison function should take its parameters by const-reference (i.e. `const Rect&`) as it doesn't need to modify them and doesn't need copies.

Answer (score 1):

`sort(lala.begin(), lala.end());`

How would `std::sort` know how to sort your `Rect`s? properly? Define a comparison function and pass it as third parameter, as you did for `std::unique`. It must take two `Rect`s as parameters and returns true if the first is < the second.

For example:

```
bool CompareRect(const Rect& first, const Rect& second) {
    return first.id<second.id;
}
```

Note that I'm passing the `Rect`'s as const references, you seem to have forgotten this in your sample.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I come up with:

I added a predicate to the sorting function:

```
bool SortRect(const Rect &first, const Rect &second)
{
    if (first.x < second.x) return true;
    if (first.x > second.x) return false;

    if (first.y < second.y) return true;
    if (first.y > second.y) return false;

    if (first.maxX < second.maxX) return true;
    if (first.maxX > second.maxX) return false;

    if (first.maxY < second.maxY) return true;
    if (first.maxY > second.maxY) return false;

    if (first.width < second.width) return true;
    if (first.width > second.width) return false;

    if (first.height < second.height) return true;
    if (first.height > second.height) return false;

    if (first.id < second.id) return true;
    if (first.id > second.id) return false;

    return false;
}
```

But I found that it has the same effect as:

```
bool SortRect(const Rect &first, const Rect &second)
{
    return first.x < second.x;
}
```

So is it like sth said, I just need to sort only the first element (for the unique function to work properly)?

Comment: No, you have to sort on all the fields that you use to compare for equality later on. If two elements are have equal `x` but differ in `y` the simplified sorting function not necessarily brings the elements with equal `x` and `y` next to each other. So the sorting function needs to be as complex as the equality function.

Comment: @Hao Wooi Lim I suppose this part should be added to the original question as edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to implement, but generally as it's been pointed, you need to design what's your comparison of your rectangles. What makes one rectangle ordered before another one in a sequence.

One of the simplest variant is to compare on the x-coordinate. More sophisticated option is to sort according to Hilbert value calculated for rectangle. See question Calculate the [Hilbert value of a point for use in a Hilbert R-Tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106237/calculate-the-hilbert-value-of-a-point-for-use-in-a-hilbert-r-tree)

Perhaps you're working on some sort of spatial index, then learn about [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree)

Comment: Woo.. hold it. I'm not sure if you are making the problem more complex: in this case all I'm concern with is removing exact duplicates.

Comment: @Hao Wooi Lim It's become more clear when you specified you are removing "exact duplicates". It's straightforward task to define equal-to and not-equal-to operations for Rect - just compare all members of Rect. However, you still need to define precisely comparison predicate for sorting. As I mentioned, you can compare on the x-coordinate or on any other component, but you have to define it clearly. Imagine two Rect objects overlap, how they should be sorted? Which is "lower" which is "higher" in a sequence?